# vis.js selectEdge and identify nodes

Tags: javascript, graph, edges, vis.js

I am using vis.js @version 4.10.0. I have requirement where I need to find the nodes during the edge selection.

I am using the below code to generate the graph.

```
    var container = document.getElementById('mynetwork');
      var data = {
        nodes: nodes,
        edges: edges
      };
      var directionInput = "UD";
      var options = {
              layout:{randomSeed:6,improvedLayout:true},
        nodes: {
          shape: 'circle',
          shadow:true,width: 2,
          size: 10,
          "color": {
          "background": "lightblue",
          "border": "lightblue",
          "highlight": "yellow"
        },
        edges:{
            shadow: true,
            arrows: 'to, from',
            color: 'red',
            font: '12px arial #ff0000',
            scaling:{
              label: true,
            }
          },
        physics:{
    stabilization: true
  },

          scaling:{
            label: {
              min:12,
              max:26
            }
          }
        }
      };
      network = new vis.Network(container, data, options);
```

Answer (score 0):

The first step is to call the 'getSelectedEdges' method on the network to find which edges are currently selected. Then, assuming your nodes and edges are instances of DataSet, you can use the methods on DataSet to find the edge in question, and then the node ids you need (this assumes that are actually trying to find the node ids that are the 'from' and 'to' for the selected edge). See: http://visjs.org/docs/data/dataset.html for a listing of the methods on DataSet.

Another option (which I use) is to create edges with ids that are informative enough to tell you what are the nodes at the endpoints of the edge. For example, one can create an edge with an id of '1_to_9'. In this case, once you know the edgeId, then you immediately know what are the node endpoints involved.